# No wifi at ALL Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, 14.10, awesome

got a bluetooth speaker tried to connect it to my laptop but while doing it messed up my wireless

Now there is no "Enable Wireless" any more

tried `iwconfig` and here is what I got

[image]

PLEASE HELP I can't leave my place to get wired connection all the time

Thanks a lot

My wireless is Intel N1030

Comment: Also happening with a Qualcomm Atheros and a Broadcom b4313 so I do not think this is limited to the Intel. The procedure is basically the same. Connect a bluetooth speaker (In my case I tried the Samsung Bluetooth earphone) and after that, the whole Network Manager started having problems. Between failed connections and not offering an option to connect there is some relation between the bluetooth and the wireless here I would think.

Comment: Yes, I've seen same trouble with one of my friends [had an intel wireless too]

Comment: Now I reinstall ubuntu [went for 14.04 LTS for now] and wireless is working but bluetooth is not

Comment: The bluetooth issue was probably fixed on a later Kernel version after 14.04. You might want to risk it if the BT is very important to you by using a mainline kernel version for ubuntu (type ubuntu kernel in google).